# Are there any direct ways to use GROUP BY with maps without explode in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, group-by, hiveql

I have the following table schema in Hive:

```
id: String
results: map <int, struct <followers: <string, array <int>>>>
```

Sample record:

```
abcd-1234-efgh-5678      {12: {"followers": {"Richard": [1, 2, 3], "Rick": [99, 10, 100]}}, 88: {"followers": {"Mina": [88], "Ray": [100000, 88, 7213, 3]}}}
```

If I want to get minimum per follower per result, I used this query:

```sql
SELECT result_id, follower_name, MIN(follower_count)
FROM the_table
LATERAL VIEW explode(results) results AS result_id, result
LATERAL VIEW explode(result.followers) followers AS follower_name, follower_count_list
LATERAL VIEW explode(follower_count_list) follower_count_list AS follower_count
GROUP BY result_id, follower_name;
```

This is correct, resulting in redundant values for the first column if it had many followers.

Are there any other ways to use `GROUP BY` on maps and arrays?

Comment: could you please also show some sample data for this table?

Comment: @vikrantrana I added an example of a record.